# symfony2 use multiple url pattern for a single Controller Action using regular expression

Tags: url, routes, symfony

Is that possible with symfony2 to define multiple url patterns for a single Controller Action using regular expressions, so we don't have to define several rules ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do you mean placeholders with requirements?

```
blog:
    pattern:   /blog/{page}
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index, page: 1 }
    requirements:
        page:  \d+
```

Here you have multiple routes defined by a placeholder, validated by regular expressions going to the same controller action.

Edit:

Each part of the url can be a placeholder.

```
blog:
    pattern:   /{type}/{page}
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index, page: 1 }
    requirements:
        type: blog|articles
        page:  \d+
```

Comment: what if I want to have type omittable? For example how would you define a route for: `/posts/sport/2`, `posts/sport`, `posts/2`. So the generic route is: `/posts/{category}/{page}`, but - obviously - it doesn't work with only default values. Is there any way to tell symfony how to recognize if second param is string/int?

Answer (score 37):

When using annotations, you can define multiple routes. Like that:

```
/**
 * @Route ("item1")
 * @Route ("item/2")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function itemAction() {

}
```

I'm using Version 2.0.9

Comment: That's really interesting, I like the idea of having the related routings defined just before an _Action_, but I'd prefer to keep everything in only one _routing.yml_ instead of spreading my routing rules in all my controllers

Comment: As you probably have the app/console open, don't forget the router:debug command to see all your routes. If you use annotations, you'll get sensible names for your routes by default, so it's actually quite easy to find the controller.

Comment: It's not possible to keep all routes in one file when you use multiple bundles (when you include routes as resource in main app `routing.yml`), so this is not really an argument for routing. Annotations are easy to use, easy debugable (`router:debug`) and configurable (you can set your own name for example: `@Route ("/", name = "homepage")`).

Answer (score 15):

Annotations example for routes with parameters :

```
/**
 * @Route("/shops/{page}", name="shops")
 * @Route("/shops/town/{town}/{page}", name="shops_town")
 * @Route("/shops/department/{department}/{page}", name="shops_department")
 */
public function shopsAction(Town $town = null, Department $department = null, $page = 1)
{ ... }
```

Then generate route in twig like this :

```
{{ path('shops_town') }}
```

or

```
{{ path('shops_town', {'town': town.id}) }}
```

or

```
{{ path('shops_department', {'department': department.id}) }}
```

Comment: Hello, are you sure about the first statement to generate an url, shouldn't it be path('shops') rather than path('shops_town') ?