# Symfony 2 - Point multiple URLs to one controller?

Tags: symfony, routes

How can I point multiple URLs to one controller? I've tried this:

```
pattern: /
defaults: { _controller: myTestController:Intro:index }
pattern: /intro
defaults: { _controller: myTestController:Intro:index }
```

But the first rule seems to be ignored and only the second one is being read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each route must be defined separately. And don't use the same identifier, otherwise you'll override the first route definition.

```
myFirstRoute:
    pattern: /
    defaults: { _controller: airpaprFramesWebsiteBundle:Intro:index }
myDuplicateRoute:
    pattern: /intro
    defaults: { _controller: airpaprFramesWebsiteBundle:Intro:index }
```

This may also help > [symfony2 use multiple url pattern for a single Controller Action using regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438698/symfony2-use-multiple-url-pattern-for-a-single-controller-action-using-regular-e)

Next time, try to use `app/console router:debug`command line to check your routes definition and figure out what's going wrong.