# Symfony2: Multiple pattern url in routing.yml

Tags: symfony, url, design-patterns, routes, yaml

I'v tried solution given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438698/symfony2-use-multiple-url-pattern-for-a-single-controller-action-using-regular-e).

But doesn't go in my case.

I'm trying the following

```
_mydomain_home_legacy_terms:
    pattern:     /{prefix}terms
    defaults: { _controller: MyDomainHomeBundle:LegacyTerms:index, prefix:'' }
    requirements:
        prefix: |legacy/|legacy_|legacy%20
```

May I use annotations?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but I dont think the value of your `prefix` requirement is valid.

Comment: the prefix needs to be a regular expression, not an array of words.  This expression matches anything that ends in terms [a-z]terms\z.  I think you should make a design decision if you want to allow for underscores, but not spaces.  This will add delays when searching for the route.