# PHP Symfony duplicate routes

Tags: php, symfony, routes

How can I create duplicate routes?

I want to have SEO and user friendly routing like:

- `/{product.slug}`
- `/{category.slug}`

But how does Symfony know which one to render? It now defaults to the last definition.

Comment: `/p/{product.slug}` and `/c/{category.slug}` is user friendly enough, isn't?

Comment: @Federkun I prefer avoiding the unnecessary nested path since this is better for SEO.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that google doesn't mind, but if you really need to do it you can create a route like `/{product_or_category}` and then [forward the request](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/forwarding.html) to ProductController or (if product is not found) CategoryController

Comment: @Federkun Well it minds a good structure. In the example you give it will be ok and maybe even more structured. But what about: `{category}/{article or product}` and so on. This method will give eventually a very poor structured sitemap. Thanks for that hint, I will look into it!

Comment: `/{product_or_category}` isn't a good structure either: what if you have a category with the same name of a product? what would you render?

Comment: @Federkun Well yes, the slugs have to be unique, but that also counts for only a product. What's best practice using Symfony?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10438844. I guess the `edit` part is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can create you route with two variables:

```
/{type}/{slug}
```

`type` would be `product`or `category`

**Or**, if you want only one variable, you can adapt your function depending on the value passed by URL.